# Why is a space required in Regex when part of match is optional?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk

I have been looking for noun phrases (noun, plus optional determiner, plus multiple optional adjectives). I wrote this long and terrible bit:

```
import argparse, re, nltk
def get_words(tagged_sentences):
words = re.findall(r'\w*\.*\,*/', tagged_sentences)
clean_word = []
for word in words:
    word = word[:-1]
    clean_word.append(word)
# return clean_word
return ' '.join(clean_word)

noun_phrase = re.findall(r'(\w*/DT\s\w*/JJ\s\w*/NN)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/JJ\s\w*/NN)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/JJ\s\w*/NNP)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/JJ\s\w*/NNPS)|(\w*/JJ\s\w*/NNS)|(\w*/JJ\s\w*/NN)|(\w*/JJ\s\w*/NNP)|(\w*/JJ\s\w*/NNPS)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/NNS)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/NN)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/NNP)|(\w*/DT\s\w*/NNPS)|(\w*/NNS)|(\w*/NN)|(\w*/NNP)|(\w*/NNPS)', tagged_sentences)
    phrases = []
for word in noun_phrase:
    phrase = get_words(str(word))
    phrases.append(phrase)
return phrases
```

At first, I was trying to use `.*` after the `NN` or the `JJ`, but that didn't work. What was I doing wrong? I did something like `(\w*/DT\s\w*/JJ.* \s\w*/NN.*)` to account for all the different ways words could be tagged as (Adjectives can be JJ,JJR,JJS while Nouns can be NN,NNS,NNP,NNPS)

```
pos_sent = 'All/DT good/JJ animals/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/, but/CC some/DT animals/NNS are/VBP more/RBR equal/JJ than/IN others/NNS ./.'
```

Then I saw this:

```
noun_phrase = re.findall(r'(\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )*(\S+\/NN )*(\S+\/NN)', tagged_sentences)
```

I liked it because it is way better in every way to what I first did. BUT I don't understand why the spaces are required after 'DT', 'JJ', and the first 'NN'(but cannot be there after the second 'NN'). I am not even sure why the two NN 'finds' cannot be placed into one.

I also preferred to use `\w` to `\S`, because it should be real letters not just not white space. Anyway, help understanding WHY would very much be appreciated.

Comment: It is not quite clear: doesn't it [work as expected](https://regex101.com/r/HpByZi/1)?

Comment: The space is only required after `\S+\/DT`, `\S+\/JJ` and `\S+\/NN`. What is the problem?

Comment: The code runs OK, but I don't understand WHY the space is required if the regular expression is optional, but can NOT exist if it is not optional.

Comment: Your comment and question do not sound cohrerent. Al the spaces in your regex are *required*, they are *NOT* optional. The groups they are in are optional. If the group pattern sequence matches a string of text, the space pattern also matches a space. What is so strange?

Comment: Thank you for viewing and commenting, Wiktor Stribizew. Why are the spaces in the regex required? (I understand the groups are optional). It is matching NN or NNS or NNPS type of thing. But in the last regex there can be no space. So the space is NOT matching a space. I am sorry I don't understand, but I am fairly new to python and this does not make sense to me.

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense. A space always matches a space. Post exact sample strings and expected output/behavior.

Comment: I thought so too (that a space always matches a space). Still, the NN is seeking / matching a NNS in both cases. I didn't need the space in the first code, but I need it in the second, shorter version.  I don't understand WHY it is required. You are saying it is NOT required. When I ran the code with and without the spaces, I got completely different results. If I added a space after the last NN, it didn't work. If I took any away from the earlier ones, it also didn't work. Those results don't fit my understanding of regex.

Comment: I have never said the spaces are not required, vice versa. Please share the code you tried, explain what you expect, and what results you get.

Comment: Here is what I wrote:
    def get_noun_phrase(pos_sent):
    noun_phrase = re.findall(r'(\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )*(\S+\/NN )*(\S+\/NN)', pos_sent)
    phrases = []
    for word in noun_phrase:
        phrase = get_words(str(word))
        phrases.append(phrase)
    return phrases
     pos_sent = 'All/DT good/JJ animals/NNS pigs/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/, but/CC some/DT animals/NNS are/VBP more/RBR equal/JJ than/IN others/NNS ./.'

Comment: See [this demo of your code above](http://ideone.com/GMuuE3) - it does not compile (`global name 'get_words' is not defined`). What is `get_words`?

Comment: I am sorry, Wiktor, Here is the missing code
    def get_words(pos_sent):
    words = re.findall(r'\w*\.*\,*/', pos_sent)
    clean_word = []
    for word in words:
        word = word[:-1]
        clean_word.append(word)
    # return clean_word
    return ' '.join(clean_word)

Comment: [Your code](http://ideone.com/Hk4ryH) does not  make much sense to me, please add the code to the question and explain what each method is supposed to do.

Comment: I added the code up above. Not all of it used in this part though.

Comment: Is `['All']`  correct result?

Comment: ['All good animals',  'some animals', 'others']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is your example text:

```
All/DT good/JJ animals/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/, but/CC some/DT
animals/NNS are/VBP more/RBR equal/JJ than/IN others/NNS ./.
```

And this is your regular expression you want to understand:

```
r'(\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )*(\S+\/NN )*(\S+\/NN)'
```

Let's take it one group at a time:

`(\S+\/DT )` matches `'All/DT '` and `'some/DT '`

`(\S+\/JJ )` matches `'good/JJ '` and `'equal/JJ '`

`(\S+\/NN )` matches nothing

`(\S+\/NN)` matches `'animals/NN'` and `'others/NN'`

You're using `re.findall()`, but that doesn't mean find all of these groups, it means consider the entire regex and find all occurrences of the entire pattern. In addition to the groups, it's key that note that the because of the question mark, your first pattern `(\S+\/DT )` is optional. Because of the asterisks, your second `(\S+\/JJ )` and third `(\S+\/NN )` patterns will match zero more times. Thus, they are also effectively optional and the only thing required is your last pattern `(\S+\/NN)`.

A quick test looks like this

```
import re
s = 'All/DT good/JJ animals/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/, but/CC some/DT animals/NNS are/VBP more/RBR equal/    JJ than/IN others/NNS ./.'
pat = r'(\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )*(\S+\/NN )*(\S+\/NN)'
res = re.findall(pat, s)
for i, g in enumerate(res):
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, g))
```

which gives this output:

```
0: ('All/DT ', 'good/JJ ', '', 'animals/NN')
1: ('some/DT ', '', '', 'animals/NN')
2: ('', '', '', 'others/NN')
```

If we remove the spaces,

```
pat2 = r'(\S+\/DT)?(\S+\/JJ)*(\S+\/NN)*(\S+\/NN)'
res2 = re.findall(pat2, s)
for i, g in enumerate(res2):
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, g))
```

the output will be exactly what you'd expect,

```
0: ('', '', '', 'animals/NN')
1: ('', '', '', 'animals/NN')
2: ('', '', '', 'others/NN')
```

i.e., only the required ones match. Your question is why? I think the issue is that you may feel you are issuing a series of patterns to look for, but you are looking for a single pattern that has multiple match groups. In other words, your regular expression requires these pattern to exist in the order you specify. If they aren't there, then sure, it doesn't matter that they are ordered, but if they are there, they have to be ordered exactly as the regex specifies.

So with the spaces `(\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )`, matches `'All/DT good/JJ '` because it literally says match 1 or more non whitespace characters plus a forward slash plus DT plus a space followed by 1 or more whitespace characters plus a forward slash plus `'JJ'`. Without the spaces `(\S+\/DT)?(\S+\/JJ)`, the match would *require* either that the entire `(\S+\/DT )` pattern NOT be there, or that if it IS there, it's definitely does NOT contain a space after `'DT'`.

I think the key is that you're matching the entire sequence. Without the space, it simply doesn't match the text anymore. If you want these patterns to be considered independently, you will need to use the pipe symbol (`|`) to indicate OR between your pattern groups.

Comment: Thank You, TSeymour! I am sorry I cannot vote you up!  Could others please, vote TSeymour up!

Answer (score 0):

What you may do is to write a linear regex using optional groups and simplify your code to only processes valid matches and leverage list comprehension:

```
import re
def get_words(tagged_sentences):
    clean_word = re.findall(r'(\w+)/', tagged_sentences)
    return ' '.join(clean_word)

tagged_sentences = 'All/DT good/JJ animals/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/, but/CC some/DT animals/NNS are/VBP more/RBR equal/JJ than/IN others/NNS ./.'
pat = r"""\w*(?:/(?:JJ\s\w*|DT\s\w*(?:/JJ\s\w*)?))?/NN(?:[SP]?|PS)"""
noun_phrase = re.findall(pat, tagged_sentences)
phrases = [get_words(str(word)) for word in noun_phrase]
print(phrases)
# => ['All good animals', 'some animals', 'others']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/4bBYwh).

The pattern extraction regex now matches:

- `\w*` - 0+ word (letter/digit/`_` chars) chars (replace `*` with `+` to match one or more)
- `(?:/(?:JJ\s\w*|DT\s\w*(?:/JJ\s\w*)?))?` - an *optional* sequence (due to `?` quantifier) of:

  - `/` - a slash
  - `(?:JJ\s\w*|DT\s\w*(?:/JJ\s\w*)?)` - either of the sequences of:

    - `JJ\s\w*` - `JJ` followed with 1 whitespace (add `+` after it to match one or more) and then 0+ word chars
    - `|` - or
    - `DT\s\w*(?:/JJ\s\w*)?` - a `DT`, then 1 whitespace, then 0+ word chars, and then an optional sequence of `/JJ`, followed with 1 whitespace and 0+ word chars
- `/NN` - a literal substring `/NN`
- `(?:[SP]?|PS)` - either `S`, or `P`, or `PS` or an empty string (since the `[SP]?` is *optional*).

The regex that gets the word from the tagged token is

```
re.findall(r'(\w+)/', tagged_sentences)
```

Here, `(\w+)/` matches and captures 1+ word chars, and they are extracted with `re.findall` while the `/` is omitted from the result as it is not part of the capturing group.

Comment: Thank You. I still don't understand why there are spaces required in this:    (r'(\S+\/DT )?(\S+\/JJ )*(\S+\/NN )*(\S+\/NN)
but cannot be after the last NN.
Your answer is very nice.  I lack some understanding.

Comment: If you have a space in between  `/DT` and `word/JJ` you must add a space in the regex pattern, or `\s+` that matches one or more any whitespace chars, otherwise there will be no match. I believe you had some experience with nltk pos based extraction grammar that parses input in its own way. Regex engine parses the string as is and if a space is on the way, it must be consumed.